# Reference Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package from Class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class library project created with Visual Studio 2015. I tried to add the package `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` to my project with NuGet. That worked out fine a you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

But whenever I try to use the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace in my project, it complains that it cannot find the given namespace.

> The type or namespace name AspNet does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

But it's clearly referenced in my project... Anyone any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Are you on Visual Studio 2015 RTM? Your references are out of date.

Comment: @opiants No, I installed the visual studio community edition.

Comment: Ok but is it the release version or beta? If you go Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio, what version does it say?

Answer (score 1):

I have just add the code below to my project.json file and rebuild the project and the problem solved,now I have access to **using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;**

```
 "frameworks": {
"dnx451": { },
"dnxcore50": { }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class library to be a `project.json` (i.e. MyClassLib.xproj) and then reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-*`.

I'm not sure a csproj class library project can consume MVC 6.